# Formatting a date in elasticsearch is not properly setting my field as a Date

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I saw that a datetime ingested is in the format of:  `yyyyMMdd HH:mm` but i didnt see anything on the website which would do it.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

When attempting to do something like the above format though it would say "spaces are not allowed"  I was not sure what was going on.  I added a photo showing this.[image: Image here]
Im not sure whats goin on.  When I attempt to add this information, I saved my index template and are going to reindex accordingly.

My end state is to intead of indexing by @timestamp, i want to index by this field: tmpstmp

I had also noticed that if i set the tmpstmp to type Date, ingestion will not like it because it is not in a format that it likes. (Shown above as 20201015 15:17)

> [WARN ] 2020-10-15 21:22:51.645 [[main]>worker0] elasticsearch - Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"transit-pittsburgh-2020.10.15", :routing=>nil, :_type=>"_doc"}, #LogStash::Event:0x2b0e6422], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"transit-pittsburgh-2020.10.15", "_type"=>"*doc", "*id"=>"XrMkLnUBgjQQ7Krx5Cr*", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse field [tmstmp] of type [date] in document with id 'XrMkLnUBgjQQ7Krx5Cr*'. Preview of field's value: '20201015 17:22'", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse date field [20201015 17:22] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"date_time_parse_exception", "reason"=>"Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"}}}}}}

I was trying to adjust logstash ingestion to say:

```
filter {
  date {
    match => ["tmstmp", "yyyyMMdd hh:mm"]

  }
}
```

but that doesnt seem to do the right job either.

Answer (score 0):

In the dev tools you can call the
GET /_index_template/template_1 add the new date format to the response and post it back.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Kibana telling me that "spaces are not allowed".

In my case I wanted to add the "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format to the `dynamic_date_formats`. I got it to work by going into dev tools in Kibana and created a component template (named my-template) there:

```
PUT /_component_template/my-template
{
  "template": {
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "dynamic_date_formats": [
          "strict_date_optional_time",
          "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "version": 1,
  "_meta": {
    "description": "blabla"
  }
}
```

And then if I view this component template in Kibana I will see this:
[image]

As I understand it this is the default:

```
dynamic_date_formats": [
  "strict_date_optional_time",
  "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z"
]
```

So I got it to work by appending my date format to the last line there.